# Unable to launch maven Test scripts from local machine:

Tags: maven-eclipse-plugin

Unable to launch maven Test scripts from local machine: :exception occurred executing command line. createprocess error=87 the parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution: The solution is to shorten the class path for maven repository, reduce depth of folder trees. Below is the steps to rectify this issue:

•   Go to Maven_Home. Update setting.xml with your customized repository name.

Example : D:\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf\setting.xml. uncomment below line in setting.xml

```
         <localRepository>D:/myrepository</localRepository> // The path to the customized local repository maven will use to store artifacts instead of Default: ~/.m2/repository.
```

•   While running Maven build from command Prompt, the repository will be created at D:/myrepository (Instead off downloading again we can copy/paste it from Default: ~/.m2/repository).

•   Update new maven local repository location from Eclipse : window  Prefrences  User setting. (see below screen shot).

•   Clean the project, In maven repository folder it should point to latest customized repository.